# EC2 cannot access aws s3 even it has IAM rule to do that

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In a VPC, I have two Subnets, one is a public subnet with an EC2 instance, the other is a private subnet with 2 EC2 instances. All 3 EC2 instances have the same IAM role to access S3.

The EC2 instance in the public subnet can access S3 directly if I login and run `aws s3 ls`. However, both of the EC2 instances in the private subnet cannot. What can be the reasons?

EC2 in the private subnet uses a Security Group that accepts traffic from the whole VPC.

EC2 in the public subnet use a Security Group that accepts traffic from *Anywhere*.

All 3 EC2 instances use the same routing table, same NACLs, use the same IAM role, with the policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I manually create a credential profile in the EC2 in the private Subnet, then it can login and access "aws s3 ls".

**Update:**
The routing table of the private subnets does have a VPC Endpoint. The routing table is:

1. dest=10.1.0.0/16 (myVPC)->target=local
2. dest=0.0.0.0/0, target=iGW
3. dest=pl-68a54001 (com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3)->target=vpce-26cf344f

Among them, #3 means the EC2 can access S3 via VPC endpoint. #2 is added because an ELB is in front of the EC2 instance and has to access internet.

Another observation: If I enable **Assign Public IP** in the private subnet and then launch a new EC2 instance, this EC2 instance can access S3. If I disable Assign Public IP in the private subnet and then launch a new EC2 instance, the new EC2 instance cannot access S3.

BTW, I already have region set as us-west-2 before running terraform:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXX]$ echo $AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE
abcdefg
[ec2-user@XXXXX]$ aws configure --profile abcdefg
AWS Access Key ID [****************TRM]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************nt+]: 
Default region name [us-west-2]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that your solution works when an instance has a Public IP address, but does not work when it does *not* have a Public IP address, suggests that the instance is actually in a public subnet.

Indeed, looking at "the routing table of the private subnets", you include this line:

```
2. dest=0.0.0.0/0, target=iGW
```

This is making the subnet a **Public Subnet** because it is pointing to an Internet Gateway.

To clarify:

- A **public subnet** is a subnet with a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway
- A **private subnet** is a subnet with a Route Table that *does not* point to an Internet Gateway

Therefore, you should remove the above entry from the Route Table for your private subnets if you actually want them to be private.

Next, it appears that you `aws s3 ls` request is not being sent to the VPC Endpoint. This might be because you are not sending traffic to `s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` as listed in your route table. Try this command:

```
aws s3 ls --region us-west-2
```

That will send the request to the S3 endpoint that would be routed via the VPC Endpoint. You should direct all of your S3 commands to that region, since the VPC Endpoint only points to the region in which it was configured.

Comment: Thanks John. aws s3 ls --region us-west-2 works! does it mean every time I send AWSCLI, I need to indicate --region explicitly. then why the public EC2 does not do that? note I did every thing in us-west-2. In fact, I created the whole VPC using terraform, which I run from a host created from us-west-2... anyway, works now with --region indicated.

Comment: Thanks John, another question: I use public route table for the private subnet because it is behind ELB so that ELB distribute traffic to it. what I learn is ELB should be in pub subnet, and ELB should be in the same net with the EC2 behind it so I need to set the EC2 with public route. please correct me if the EC2 behind the ELB does not need to have public route

Comment: You can default the region by using the `aws configure` command. Set the region to `us-west-2` and then all your `aws` commands will be automatically directed to [that region's endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

Comment: Only the Load Balancer needs to be in a Public Subnet because it needs to be accessible from the Internet. If the other instances do not need to be accessible from the Internet, then they can be placed in a private subnet. All subnets within a VPC can communicate with each other, so instances do not need to be in the same subnet as the Load Balancer -- this happens automatically via the `dest=10.1.0.0/16 (myVPC)->target=local` route table entry (that you cannot remove).

Comment: Thanks John. I have already configure the region that way. see my update. must due to some other reasons. and thanks to confirm that subnet behind ELB does not need to be public.

Comment: Environment Variables can override these settings, so check if any relevant ones are set.

Comment: Excellent answer - this just helped me to solve my s3 connectivity problems.

Answer (score 5):

When you place the EC2 in Private Subnet, Network level it doesn't have access to S3 (Not an issue with the IAM policy). To allow outbound access to S3 from EC2 instances in Private Subnet, you have the following options.

1. [VPC endpoints for S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)
2. [NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

Out of the two approaches, if you plan to allow access only to S3 from EC2 instance in Private Subnet, configure VPC endpoints for S3.

Comment: ThX Ashan, the routing table of the private subnet DO have vpc endpoint. ie. routing table is: 1) dest=10.1.0.0/16 (myVPC)->target=local 2) dest=0.0.0.0/0, target=iGW, 3)dest=pl-68a54001 (com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3)->target=vpce-26cf344f, among them, 3) means the EC2 can access S3 via VPC endpoint. ( 2) is added bez ELB in front of the EC2 has to access internet). another observation: If I enable public IP assign in the private subnet and then launch a new EC2, this EC2 can access s3, if I disable public IP assign in the private subnet and then launch a new EC2, the new EC2 cannot access s3.